# How to calculate new standard deviation based on formula given only the mean and set standard deviations

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, means

I currently have the mean and standard deviation, I need to calculate the new standard deviation given a formula:

```
µX = 9.5 and µY = 6.8
σX = 0.4 and σY = 0.1

with the equation X-Y
```

What steps do I go though to calculate the new mean and standard deviation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are **independent**, then the **variance** of $aX+bY$ is $a^2$ times the variance of $X$ plus $b^2$ times the variance of $Y$. Here $a=1$ and $b=-1$.  But the post does not say $X$ and $Y$ are independent. With just the information given, we cannot compute the variance of $X-Y$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: That makes sense, however, I know that the answer to the mean is -2.7 and the standard deviation should be 0.412, however, with these variables, I cannot seem to figure out the standard deviation after the equation.

Comment: @JessePFrancis, I will look over these, thanks!

Comment: For **independent** $X$ and $Y$, the formula I mentioned gives that the standard deviation of $X-Y$ is $\sqrt{(0.4)^2+(0.1)^2}$.

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes much more sense, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Variance($V$) of $(X-Y)=V(X)+V(Y)-2Cov(X,Y)$ where $Cov(X,Y)$ is the covariance between $X$ and $Y$.

Mean($\mu$) of $(X-Y)=\mu(X)-\mu(Y)$

So you need information regarding the covariance to calculate the answers properly if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

**EDIT:**
$$Cov(X,Y)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(x_i-\bar x)(y_i-\bar y)}{\sigma_x\sigma_y}$$

Comment: Unfortunately, that is all of the data that I was given by my professor and from what I have seen it is possible to calculate this number, however, I still cannot seem to calculate the standard deviation.

Comment: What is the standard deviation according to answer?